# CSS keyframes animation for continuously shifting text from right to left

Tags: html, css

I am working with text animation. As you will see here, at the end of animation-duration is occurs abruptly transition cut.

I want to have continuously shifting text.

```css
     text {
            animation: scrollText 5s infinite linear;
            opacity: 0.5;
            stroke: #bec1ce;
          }
    
        @keyframes scrollText {
          from {
            transform: translateX(0%);
          }
          to {
            transform: translateX(-50%);
          }
        }
```

My full code is at [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwkof41n/24/)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```css
.selector { animation: scrollText 5s infinite linear; }

@keyframes scrollText {
  from { transform: translateX(100%); }
  to { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

[image: demo]

To make it looks seamlessly shifting, you gotta set the end state to look the same as the start.

**Edit: no space in between**

As you don't want any space in between the transition, we can achieve that with this trick.

First, let's double the text so we will have something to fill up the space.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 700 72">
   <text x="0" y="70">
     text&nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;text
   </text>
   <text x="0" y="70">
     text&nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;text
   </text>
</svg>
```

Then we create 2 keyframes, one for the starting text and one for the ending. These two texts will run next to each other infinitely.

```css
@keyframes scrollTextStart {
  from { transform: translateX(0%); }
  to { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes scrollTextEnd {
  from { transform: translateX(100%); }
  to { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

And the CSS will look like this

```css
text:nth-child(1) {
    animation: scrollTextStart 2s infinite linear;
}
text:nth-child(2) {
    animation: scrollTextEnd 2s infinite linear;
}
```

[image: demo-no-space]

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nrgyL530/13/)

Comment: Beautiful. But I don't want spaces. There should be continuous writing.

Comment: @nigranac You will need JS for that. I would start by looking into the `animationend` event listener.

Comment: @nigranac I've just updated my answer without using JS. Hope it help.

Comment: nice :))))..thanks a lot @phucbm

Comment: @nigranac Can you mark my answer as an accepted one? Thank you.

Comment: I just said it's good because you suggested a solution. It still makes cuts in this structure.Okey? @phucbm

Comment: @nigranac Okay then.